# sending session id with uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I want to send the session_id in uploadify using scriptData, I'm trying following in jQuery code:

```
'scriptData':{'session_id':'<?php echo session_id(); ?>'}
```

and on php

```
$session_id = $_REQUEST['session_id'];
```

But the problem is that instead of getting session id, i get this value

```
<?php echo session_id(); ?>
```

If i try without quotes in around php code in the scriptData, it gives syntax error. Can someone please help me how can i send the session_id value. Thanks.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451691/javascript-basic-syntax-error)?

Comment: Sorry for repeating, I'm just so much stuck in it, cant make it work and dont understand whats problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your php doesn't get executed in the javascript code. Probable because it's in a javascript file, not in a PHP.

The simplest (and dirtiest) solution would be to move that code into your PHP file in order to get that bit of PHP code executed.

Comment: Thanks. PHP code was not being executed as it was in separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a hidden input in your php page and access it with jQuery.

```
'scriptData':{'session_id': $('#sessionID')}
```